# Help with quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, superposition, quantum-states

[All angles are measured from the vertical clockwise.]

> Let a photon have a properly normalized quantum state given by the state vector $|30>$.
>
> Rewriting this state vector in the form $a|0> + b|90>$, what is $a$?

Attempt:

I have no idea my prof never went over this. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: In its current form this question should be closed until its notation is completely clarified.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the numbers in the state vectors are related to the angles of polarization. The, in general, complex numbers $a$ and $b$ are the coefficients to describe the state vector $|30>$ in the base $|0>$ and $90>$, i.e., in terms of the $0$ and $90$ degrees polarization vectors. You can find them easily by considering the projections of the normalized state vector $|30>$ on the zero and 90 degrees axes. Thus $$a=\cos{(30°)}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ and $$b=\cos{(60°)}=\frac{1}{2}$$